# How to make a PHP library work in java environment?

Tags: java, php

i have a php library which is in php. can i have this lib to work in java environment like calling the functionalists of the lib to work exactly like a java lib?

Regards
Tony

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java runs on the JRE as a platform.  The PHP interpreter run natively on the OS on which it runs.

The best you could do is run PHP as a system process passing the PHP file you want to run as an argument, and capture that process' output.  (ie: run "/path/to/php myfile.php", and read the output).

However, I should warn you that this is a **horribe** idea, and you should really re-think what you're doing.  You java code will loose it's portability completely, as well as become awfully designed.

Comment: Yep! the prior answer had less elaboration and I agree that running php as a system process is horrible. +1.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: No

Long answer: No, you can't... They are two completely different languages.

Comment: Why can't I? `Runtime.getRuntime.exec("php <your script name>">;` Moreover, have you heard of http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/ and calls could be sent over HTTP, correct?

Comment: @verisimilitude `calling the functionalists of the lib to work exactly like a java lib`, I catch that he wants to do it like calling a native lib, you got that, correct?

Comment: @verisimilitude I have a feeling you misread the question. In any case, have a good day, I'm off to eat some uttapam

Comment: Well, you can have, save some for me too, I'd love to have it :)